# Deep linking is not working in Android pie?

Tags: android, branch, deep-linking, android-version

I am using Branch.io for deeplinking .so except only android 9 , it's working properly on all the devices . if i click link on android 9 devices then it directly opens the link in browser ,but instead of this it should open the Application .

please help me.

The below code i am using to handle the link response when clicks.
so after click on the link it should open the App but it's not opening the app , its opening the link in browser. i don't know what's happening wrong`enter code here`

I have followed each and every step from below doucments.
https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/

Comment: Can you provide code and outputs please?

Comment: facing same issue, someone please help